# Microcontroller I2C and SPI protocol

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, digital-logic, i2c, circuit-protection

I have STM32F401RCT6, ATmega328p, and ESP32 microcontrollers in my circuit. Will I have any problems if I connect the processor directly to an I2C line, otherwise what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Why is there SPI mentioned in your question? The schematic doesn't show any component you reference in the question, the question doesn't mention any voltage levels involved which would be one of the first things to look out for - and the sequencing of the voltages...

Comment: There are BMP180, MPU6050 0.96 inch OLED screen, DS1307 RTC sensors on the I2C line and all of them operate at 3.3V level.

Comment: Microcontrollers operate at STM and ESP 3.3V, ATMEGA 5V level.

Comment: You don't say what these are supposed to do on the same I2C bus. Whether you can connect some things on the bus is different from will it work, because we don't know what you expect the MCUs to do on the same bus.

Answer (score 1):

The typical characteristics for the Atmega328p for detection of the high level on a pin is given in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf#page=538) in chapter 32.7 with a voltage above 2.6 V. For a low level it's below 2.1 V.

Both values are with a supply voltage of 5 V. These levels are no issue if the bus is operated at 3.3 V. As I²C is a open drain (or collector) protocol the bus can only go as high as the pull-up resistors allow. So simply connecting the Atmega328p to the I²C lines is fine - as long as you make sure you never configure the pins as push-pull with a high output.

As your question also mentions SPI - this is not true for SPI as it uses a push-pull configuration for the pins when they are active, which would mean that the Atmega is pushing 5 V into 3.3 V components, which might work for some (the STM for example often has 5 V tolerant pins) but not for others.